# Run a Rails rake task from view and generate rake task results in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

I'm trying to help a non-technical user run a specific rails rake task and be able to see the results of the rake task in their browser.

Below is my rake task code:

```
namespace :partner do

  task :report => :environment do
    csv_output = Partner.generate_report
    csv_output.split("\n").each {|row| puts row}
  end

  task :sample_report => :environment do
    csv_output = Partner.generate_report(30)
    csv_output.split("\n").each {|row| puts row}
  end
end
```

Currently I just run rake partner:report and a bunch of data shows up in terminal but I would like for them to be able to press a button on a View page, run the rake task, and then see the results directly in the View.

Any ideas or suggestions would be MUCH APPRECIATED.

Comment: How long takes the task to run?

Comment: takes about 20 minutes and it spits out a CSV within terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want to look to a background task gem for that purpose.

Have a look into these:

https://github.com/defunkt/resque

http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think resque and delayed job are great for running tasks in the background but what I"m trying to accomplish is running the above task rake partner:report in a View. And then having the results spit out in another View page. Currently I can only run that task within terminal and it outputs all the CSV report within terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: My idea was to transform the rake task into a background job and instead of printing to the terminal you just push it to the client with something like faye. Well, you don't need to use any of this, but I think you must change the task so it returns something instead of printing.

Comment: Okay so I was actually able to run rake task directly within my controller index action: I'm wondering how can I print the result in my View index.html.erb page rather than the report showing up as CSV in Terminal                                               def index
    t = system('rake partner:report')
    puts Rake::Task.task_defined?("rake partner:report") 
    puts t.inspect()